# adding one DIV creates many white space

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML / CSS code:

**HTML**

```
<div id = "content-wrapper">
<div class="stickyheader"> 
       <a href="index.php"><div id="logo"></div></a>    
       <div class="nav">
            <ul class="top_nav">
               <li>Home</li>
               ...
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div class="central_img_front">Some text</div>
    <div class="welcome_container">Test</div>
</div>

...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.stickyheader {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 138px;
    padding-top: 24px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
#content-wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 162px;
}
.welcome_container {
    margin: 413px auto 55px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 760px;
}
.central_img_front {
    background-image: url(http://modeles-de-lettres.org/test/images/slide12.jpg);
    width: 1920px;
    height: 413px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-460px;
}
```

Full JSFiddle code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ugnmc/

[image]

My problem is with `content-wrapper` part. There are two `div`s inside this `div`:

```
div.central_img_front
div.welcome_container
```

I need those divs to be exactly under `div.stickyheader`. Now as you can see in fiddle, `div.central_img_front` is pushed too far to the bottom (there are a lot of white space under `div.stickyheader`).If I remove `div.welcome_container` from HTML then everything is OK. So,

I really cannot get it - why `div.welcome_container` affects `div.central_img_front`?

**EDIT:**

```
div.central_img_front
```

is positioned absolute, because it is in container (wrapper). If I remove position:absolute, then it is positioned incorrectly and .

Comment: Isn't it because you have too big height of your header ? Try setting div.stickyheader.height to 50px and div.content-wrapper.margin-top to 50px

Comment: Remove/reduce the top margin (413px) of .welcome container.. so this will reduce the empty space between the menu and image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white space is caused by `.welcome-container`, which has a huge `margin-top`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ugnmc/1/)

Change is:

```
.welcome_container {
    margin: 0px auto 55px auto; 
    // was margin: 413px auto 55px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 760px;
}
```

Comment: If I remove margin-top then div.welcomecontainer and other content is on top off central_img_front. See website: http://modeles-de-lettres.org/test/index.php?p=mindex

Comment: div.central_img_front should be on the white space, but div.welcome_container should be just under div.central_img_front, this is why margin-top was set.

Comment: `.central_img_font` is jumping "ahead" of `.welcome_container` because of `position:absolute;`, if you remove that - divs will be in proper order.

Comment: If I remove absolute, then image is positioned incorrectly (see here now http://modeles-de-lettres.org/test/index.php?p=mindex). This is becaues it is in wrapper. I will update my question.

Comment: Change `left: -460px;` to `margin-left: -460px;` for that pic.

Answer (score 1):

The position:absolute takes the div.central_img_front out of line and the div.welcome_container slides in before it. Can you just remove it?

Answer (score 0):

hei men, check these fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/N269j/.

The problem are the `margings` and the `heights`.

Comment: If I do like this now div.welcomecontainer and other content is on top off central_img_front. See website: http://modeles-de-lettres.org/test/index.php?p=mindex